Avoid doubling every rule for NEWLINE vs DOUBLE_NEWLINE
I want blank new lines to be syntactically significant (optimization for leaf leaning trees [[[a, b], c, d], e, [g], f] == [a b | c d | e [g] f] but with \n\n instead of |). But the only way I can disambiguate is by doubling every definition depending on whether it ended with a single or double new line.
Essentially the problem is: I don't want the first rule tree only ever being used, and the second rule tree_d never being used. But I still need the Indenter to work (not deindenting blank new lines).
tree: tree_d? (NAME NL)+
tree_dnl: tree_dnl? (NAME NL)* NAME DNL

Is there a way to reduce this duplication.
from lark import Lark
from lark.indenter import Indenter

grammar="""\
start: tree
tree: tree_d? node+
tree_d: tree_d? node* node_d
?node: leaf | sub_tree
?node_d: leaf_d | sub_tree_d
leaf: NAME NL
leaf_d: NAME DNL

?sub_tree: _INDENT tree _DEDENT
?sub_tree_d: _INDENT tree_d _DEDENT

NL: /\\n */
DNL: /\\n\\n */

%declare _INDENT _DEDENT
%import common.CNAME -> NAME
"""

# [[[a, b], c, d], e, [g], f]
sample_string ="""\
a
b

c
d

e
    g
f
"""


class TreeIndenter(Indenter):
    NL_type = 'NL'
    OPEN_PAREN_types = []
    CLOSE_PAREN_types = []
    INDENT_type = '_INDENT'
    DEDENT_type = '_DEDENT'
    tab_len = 4

parser = Lark(grammar, postlex=TreeIndenter(), debug=True)
for i, t in enumerate(parser.lex(sample_string)):
    print((t.line, t.column), repr(t))
parse_tree = parser.parse(sample_string)
print(parse_tree.pretty())


Your best bet is probably to just write a custom postlexer. Check the source code for the Indenter and see if you can figure out how it works and how you can adapt it to your usecase (I am not quite sure I understand your rules quite correctly to try and implement it myself)

Thanks! I just needed to insert a token after _DEDENT in certain circumstances
